# java.lang.IllegalAccessError when trying to access a public class

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4

I have two projects in my workspace using `Eclipse Kepler`, `Adapter` (contains package adapter) and `TestCases` (contains package tests) that I create to contain `JUnit` test cases for classes in `Adapter`. I use different projects because I'm told to do that so I can't move the test package to the same project as the class being tested.

Here's the `Config.java` structure

```
package adapter;

public class Config {
    //...
}
```

And here's the `TestSuite.java` structure

```
package tests;

import adapter.Config;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    // class files of the test cases
})

public class TestSuite {
    //...
    @BeforeClass
    public static void main setUp() {
         //...
         Config.parse();
         //...
    }
}
```

I have included the `Adapter` project in `TestCases'` build path, but when I tried to run `TestSuite.java`, it fails and here's the failure trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class adapter.Config from class tests.TestSuite
    at tests.TestSuite.setUp(TestSuite.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Prior to this I had problem where I can't import `adapter.config` because `Eclipse` claimed it is not visible. I searched for a while and what fixed it was re-importing all the jars that I included in `TestCases`. But now I have this problem and I can't seem to find the solution.

It previously didn't do this so I figured the run-time class is probably different from the current one. There's no compile error at all. I'm not sure if I do this right but I removed all the class file and let `Eclipse` recompile everything by saving each file, but the same problem still persists. I don't know what else I should check.

Comment: Which version of java are you using? Also is your jre the same as your jdk version?

Comment: @coolgirl I'm using java 8u121, and yes it's the same.